# Facing router error when revising the component heirarchy

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

The use case is a little bit complicated and I had to turn to [Plunker's help to demonstrate the issue](https://plnkr.co/edit/usO5DQbXBLfA8UjWF5CI?p=preview).

The whole idea is to change the page's design based on the window's size in a live way. In the given link, if the window is less than 600px the parent template shows a 2-column table and when it's over 600px, it shows the content in a 3-column table (just an example).

The steps to replicate the issue (you'll find them in the Plunker page as well):

1. Open your developer tools
2. Click on "Open middle child"
3. Click on "Open grandchild"
4. Click on "Open middle child"
5. Resize the preview window in a way that if it was less than 600px, make it larger. Otherwise, make it smaller than 600px (just change the state)
6. Click on "Open grandchild"

The error is:

- After step 5, the "Grandchild" should not have been shown
- Following step 6 will result in an error that you can see in console

I believe the problem relies on the fact that there are more than one `<router-outlet>` and switching between them is not supported by Angular. I just hope there's a way to fix this!

And here's the `app.ts`'s code to comply with SO:

```
//our root app component
import { Component, NgModule, VERSION, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div (window:resize)="onResize($event)" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
      Steps to replicate the problem:
      <ol>
        <li>Open your developer tools</li>
        <li>Click on "Open middle child"</li>
        <li>Click on "Open grand child"</li>
        <li>Click on "Open middle child"</li>
        <li>Resize the preview window in a way that if it was less than 600px, make it larger. Otherwise, make it smaller than 600px (just change the state)</li>
        <li>Click on "Open grand child"</li>
      </ol>
      Notes:
      <ul>
        <li>After step 5, the "Grand child" should have not been shown</li>
        <li>Following step 6 will result in an error that you can see in console</li>
      </ul>
      <table *ngIf="columns == 2" class="frame">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">2-Column design - "{{router.routerState.snapshot.url}}"</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a [routerLink]="['/middle-child']">Open middle child</a></td>
          <td><router-outlet></router-outlet></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table *ngIf="columns == 3" class="frame">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">3-Column design - "{{router.routerState.snapshot.url}}"</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a [routerLink]="['/middle-child']">Open middle child</a></td>
          <td><router-outlet></router-outlet></td>
          <td>3rd column</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  name:string;
  columns: number = 2;
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.columns = window.innerWidth < 600 ? 2 : 3;
  }
  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
    this.columns = event.target.innerWidth < 600 ? 2 : 3;
  }
}

@Component({
  template: `
  <table>
    <tr><td>Middle child here</td></tr>
    <tr><td><a [routerLink]="['/middle-child/grand-child']">Open grand child</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><router-outlet></router-outlet></td></tr>
  </table>
  `
})
export class MiddleChild {}

@Component({
  template: `Grand child`
})
export class GrandChild {}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'middle-child', component: MiddleChild, children: [
        { path: 'grand-child', component: GrandChild }
      ] }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [ App, MiddleChild, GrandChild ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two different tables toggled by number of columns, which confuses Angular Router. I believe.

I improved your code with below.

```
<td [colSpan]="columns">{{columns}}
...
<td *ngIf="columns == 3">
```

Check my edited version: https://plnkr.co/edit/hGDJgT8rF7hl2FOZw3Eh?p=preview

Comment: That was just a way to demonstrate the concept. In reality, it won't be that simple. The whole design and hierarchy of tags might be totally different, instead of just changing from 2 columns to 3 columns.

Comment: No matter what, adding multiple tables containing different route-outlet which definitely confuses Angular, preventing it from managing component state for you. You cannot go with this approach.

Comment: That's the point of this question, asking for a way to replace the whole component hierarchy without breaking stuff.

Comment: You need to show your actual component code. Otherwise, I cannot give a general solution.

Comment: I don't have a specific code in mind. I am looking for a general solution.

Comment: I see. Just like what most authors write in book. This will be a pitfall. You should avoid toggling route-outlet and apply true/false assertion on component element only. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147763/discussion-between-mehran-and-wannadream).